# How do I retrieve a custom post type taxonomy key in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm trying to retrieve the custom post type taxonomy (key?) when on the archive.php page.

My site has 4 custom post types, which will all use the archive.php to display posts:

ie. 
http://localhost/thebridestree/vendor_category/beauty-and-makeup-3/
http://localhost/thebridestree/pinboard_category/accessories/

On the archive.php page, I need to be able to retrieve the taxonomy (key?):

ie. vendor_category or pinboard_category.

From here, I can display posts with query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'         => 'vendor',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'vendor_category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $catslug,
```

I've searched for hours on this one - most answers are to do with retrieving the c ategory ie. beauty-and-makeup-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `get_query_var('taxonomy')` will return current taxonomy and 
`get_query_var( 'term' )` will return current `term / category`
create separate arrays. Finally fetch all the posts relate to your criteria.

E.g:

`post type = 'vendor'` , `taxonomy = 'vendor_category'` and `term ='beauty-and-makeup-3'`.

```
<?php 
    $taxonmy    = get_query_var('taxonomy'); 
    $term       = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $tax_array  = array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonmy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
                );

    $args = array(
                'post_type'  => 'vendor',
                'nopaging'   => true,
                'tax_query'  => array(
                                  'relation' => 'AND',
                                  $tax_array
                               )
               );
    $postsobject = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($postsobject->have_posts()): $postsobject->the_post();

           ?>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
           <?php 

    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Norman, this worked perfectly!

It is retrieving the taxonomy and term. I've now got separate problem with retrieving the post_type now (for some reason this returns as nothing).

I think this might be related to how I am using the WP templates. ie. I have the following:

/Vendor/ -> archive-vendor.php (Displays with my code, category listing). -- clicking a category automatically calls archive.php page -- /Vendor/Beauty-and-makeup-3/ -> archive.php (At this point is where I have above code).